# If I make one object with 2 hair particle systems, can I make each particle system on a different layer? If so, how? (blender 2.83)

Tags: particles, layers

If I make one object with 2 hair particle systems, can I make each particle system on a different layer?  If so, how? (blender 2.83)

Answer (score 1):

never mind, figured it out.
I didn't see the field weights section in the particle settings, that fixed it.